# How can i fix the height of the body in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The height of the screen on mobile is not 100%. It looks good on bigger devices though.

This is how the page looks [DESKTOP IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdQwP.jpg)

I tried to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />` but it only makes the content bigger and it wont solve the problem.

This is how it looks after i used that. [PHONE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0SFV.png)

The footer moves down the more i add stuff in the content. I also tried to give height 100% to the body but that wont fix it also. Is it possible to make the page fit the size of the device so it looks same in every device.

Comment: can you create a snippet with relevant code?

Comment: This is the [CODE](http://pastebin.com/ZgeWF8eP) structure.

Comment: @YllzaCanaj try to set `body { min-height: 100vh }`

Comment: @fcalderan Thanks,  it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting the height on the body is not a good idea. You better work with a sticky footer if that is what you want. (For example: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)
2. Try making your webpage responsive by using frameworks like Bootstrap. (Example: https://getbootstrap.com/)
3. If you really insist to set the height on the body, please add your html to make sure we can show you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I tried to give the footer this style : position: absolute; bottom 0; that is what you meant right ? But that is not what i am asking for. The page is 100% responsive. What i am trying to do is making the body fit all the devices so that is looks same on each of them.

Comment: You simply cannot set the body to fit the screen of every device & maintain the layout on all devices at the same time. Shouldn't mobile phones, tablets & desktops have an specific design to make sure it looks good on every device instead of making it look the same? I don't think the website is readable when you just make the desktop version smaller to fit the phone-screen...